# JQuery live not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
$('.enter').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

for some reason this does not get called on the specified button, BUT, when f12 is pressed and developer tools pops up this works!? I am using live on all other elements and it works fine... very strange and hard to debug. any help much appreciated!

Comment: is your element with the class of enter actually on the page when the dom is generated ?

Comment: put an 'alert("I was triggered");' after the 'e.preventDefault();' to see if it realy does not get triggered.

Comment: Do you use any console.log before this code?

Comment: Why just preventDefault in it? Use jquery "on" as it is more elegant solution. As you said it is working with console enabled you probably have some log in your code causing exception when console is disabled.

Comment: i do have console logging in the body(i haven't posted this) i think that might well be the problem here. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, it may be better that you use `.on()`.
For example :

```
$(document).on('.enter', 'click', function(){
   ...
});
```

As jquery doc said `.live()` is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/

I had some issue by using `.live()` on IE if the element is created after define the event.